# Exporting SQL Server table containing a large text column

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have to export a table from a SQL Server, the table contains a column that has a large text content with the maximum length of the text going up to 100,000 characters.

When I use Excel as an export destination, I find out that the length of this text is capped and truncated to 32,765.

Is there an export format that preserves the length?

Note:

1. I will eventually be importing this data into another SQL Server
2. The destination SQL Server is in another network, so linked servers and other local options are not feasible
3. I don't have access to the actual server, so generating back up is difficult

Answer (score 3):

As is documented in the [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) the maximum characters that can be stored in a single Excel cell is 32,767 characters; hence why your data is being truncated.

You might be better off exporting to a CSV, **however**, note that Quote Identified CSV files aren't supported within `bcp`/`BULK INSERT` until SQL Server 2019 (currently in preview). You can use a characters like `||` to denote a field delimited, however, if you have any line breaks you'll need to choose a different row delimitor too. SSIS, and other ETL tools, however, *do* support quote identified CSV files; so you can use something like that.

Otherwise, if you need to export such long values and want to use Excel as much as you can (which I actually personally don't recommend due to those awful ACE drivers), I would suggest exporting the `(n)varchar(MAX)` values to something else, like a text file, and naming each file with the value of your Primary Key included. Then, when you import the data back you can retrieve the `(n)varchar(MAX)` value again from each individual file.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth. Great answer.

Comment: great - thanks for the response. I'm not keen on excel, I'm thinking of going with CSV - but anything robust would be great.

Comment: When ever you can @tempidope don't use excel. Excel can open flat files, as can many other programs, so try and stick with that.

Answer (score -1):

The .sql is the best format for sql table. Is the native format for sql table, with that, you haven't to concert the export.

Comment: This is a comment, and is far too brief for an answer. I suggest expanding greatly on this, however, a `.sql` file is far from a SQL Server table.